# Flutter rangeError (index) Valid value range is empty

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

I am buidling an app which takes a list of people (from another class 'people1') and a list of bool if people are here or not ("peoplePres"). So I run the program in a series of loops which is an algorithm I thought of. The error i got is

> rangeError (index) Valid value range is empty

I am sitting here for about 9 hours trying to solve the problem and i dont know how if you can help that will be amazing.
also I am not sure I am saving the List "lastPres" list correctly using shared preferences packages.
Thank you in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> people1;
  List<bool> peoplePres;
  Result({this.people1, this.peoplePres});
  List<String> lastPres = [];
  void initState() {
    _lastZakif();
  }

  void _lastZakif() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    lastPres = (prefs.getStringList('lastPres') ?? 0);
  }
void _loadingNew() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    lastPres = people1;
    await prefs.setStringList('lastPres', lastPres);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = 0; //count for how many people are here
    int count2 = 1; //count for the new order

    List<int> list1 = []; //List with the algorithm
    List<int> list2 = []; //List with the new order

    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      //counting People that are here
      if (peoplePres[i] == true) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // Declaring a list which will be the index for the next Zkifut
      list1[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      //Applying the algorithm
      int num1 = count ~/ 3;
      if (num1 % 3 == 2) {
        num1 += 1;
      }
      list1[i] = list1[i] + num1 ~/ 3 - count;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // making the new schedule for absent people but starting with 0
      if (peoplePres[i] == false) {
        list2[i] = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // makeing the new schedule pos num
      if ((list1[i] >= 0) && (peoplePres[i] == true)) {
        list2[i] = count2;
        count2++;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // makeing the new schedule neg num
      if ((list1[i] < 0) && (peoplePres[i] == true)) {
        list2[i] = count2;
        count2++;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // makeing the new schedule for absent people
      if ((peoplePres[i] == false) && (list2[i]) != 0) {
        list2[i] = count2;
        count2++;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      people1[list2[i]] = people1[i];
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Result',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: people1.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, value) {
            return Card(
              color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
              elevation: 3,
              child: Container(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Text('${value + 1}'),
                  title: Text(
                    people1[value],_loadingNew();
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: on what line is the error?

Comment: the error happens when i compile the code not in any line particular which is why you dont see a line I the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set values using `operator[]=` with empty lists which will cause a `RangeError` to be thrown.

For example, at the beginning of your build method, you create two lists:

```dart
    List<int> list1 = []; //List with the algorithm
    List<int> list2 = []; //List with the new order
```

And then in your second loop you try to assign to an index in the empty list:

```dart
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // Declaring a list which will be the index for the next Zkifut
      list1[i] = i; // This is where your first exception is coming from
    }
```

You can't just write to an arbitrary index in a list in Dart since you need to ensure that the index you're writing to is at within the range of 0 and `list.length - 1`. If your list is empty, the valid range is [0, 0], which means you'll always throw a `RangeError`.

You've got a few options to fix this:

1. If you know the length of the list in advance, you can pre-allocate the list to be of a specific size and leave the rest of your code as-is:

```dart
    List<int> list1 = List(length);
```

2. You can initialize with an empty list and then add each element to the end of the list:

```dart
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      list.add(i); // instead of list1[i] = i;
    }
```

3. If you know what the content of the list should be when you're initializing it, you can build the list using a collection-based for loop, similar to Python's list comprehension:

```dart
    List<int> list1 = [for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) i];
```